# Is it possible to "disable" the GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I have 3 projects in my repository https://github.com/JonkiPro. Projects `Movie-Database-with-Social-Network` and `Social-Network` are created a long time ago and I am ashamed of them because they were written when I was still a poor programmer. However, due to fondness, I would not like to remove them and somehow "hide" (I do not want to set as private). Is there any way for GitHub to turn off the project and make it invisible?

Comment: Pay $7/month for GitHub, you can set it is private repository. https://github.com/settings/billing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [archiving them](https://help.github.com/articles/archiving-repositories/). This doesn't hide them, but it does send a pretty clear message to anybody looking at them:

> You can archive a repository to make it read-only for all users and indicate that it's no longer actively maintained.

This is done in your repository's settings, in the "danger zone" area. Make sure to read the warnings when you do this. It's important to understand what you're doing.